# angular 2 change detection

Tags: angular, typescript

I want create a custom property decorator for Angular 2 component, which will listen changes to 3rd party source and bind this property to a source value. Is there any way to force Angular 2 to detect changes without having a reference to a NgZone or ChangeDetectorRef?  Or maybe there is a way to get ref to NgZone outside angular component. Thanks.